# Presto SQL Count Occurences In Array Column And Add Missing Timestamps

Tags: sql, presto

My Presto SQL statement aggregates multiple rows that all have a datetime into a single row with an array of those datetimes (all the other properties are the same among those rows). So I end up with something like this (there are an arbitrary number of columns, this is simplified):

```
id | timestamps
1    [ 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000, 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000, 2018-10-01 01:00:00.000, 2018-10-01 01:00:00.000, 2018-10-01 01:00:00.000]
2    [ 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000, 2018-10-01 01:00:00.000, 2018-10-01 01:00:00.000]
```

I want to essentially perform three steps, I want to count the occurrences of each date per row, so maybe something like:

```
id | timestamps
1    [ { 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 : 2}, { 2018-10-01 01:00:00.000 : 3}]
2    [ { 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 : 1}, { 2018-10-01 01:00:00.000 : 2}]
```

Then, given a start and end, like 2018-10-01 00:00:00.00 to 2018-10-01 02:00:00.00, fill in any missing timestamps with a 0 count

```
id | timestamps
1    [ { 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 : 2}, { 2018-10-01 01:00:00.000 : 3}, { 2018-10-01 02:00:00.000 : 0}]
2    [ { 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 : 1}, { 2018-10-01 01:00:00.000 : 2}, { 2018-10-01 02:00:00.000 : 0}]
```

And then I want to supply a percentage, like 60%, and figure out the maximum count that occurs at least that often and save that as a column for the row. So this would look like:

```
id   | timestamps                                                                                      | col3
1    [ { 2018-10-01 00:00:00.00 : 2}, { 2018-10-01 01:00:00.000 : 3}, { 2018-10-01 02:00:00.000 : 0}]   2
2    [ { 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000: 1}, { 2018-10-01 01:00:00.000 : 2}, { 2018-10-01 02:00:00.000 : 0}]   1
```

For the first row, 3 only occurs 33% of the time while 2 occurs 66% of the time (for the count of 3, it includes a count of 2, and a count of 1), so given the threshold of 60%, the number I want to capture is 2. On the second row, 2 only occurs 33% of the time and 1 occurs 66% of the time, so the number to capture is 1. If 30% was supplied as the threshold for the second row, then I'd capture 2.

Are any of these steps possible in SQL? If so, what are the functions/mechanisms that would be used to perform these steps?

Comment: Just curious, but were you successful in completing any of these steps using Presto SQL? If so, mind posting your answer? Thanks and good luck!